# Determinant of the sum of a circulant matirx and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can we compute the determinant of the sum of a circulant matirx and a diagonal matrix in general? In other words, can we compute the determinant of those matrices which have circulant properties but the diagonal elements are not the same?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Inequalities that can determine the upper bound of the determinant will also be fine. Thanks!

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493910/determinant-of-circulant-like-matrix).